# Trying to replay a GPX route in javascript, but struggling with delaying the waypoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I've got a number of GPX files that contain routes I want to replay within a node.js script. This is to support testing an geo application so I'd like to replay the way points with the same time differences as when the route was captured. So for example, if I have a file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx
  version="1.1"
  creator="Runkeeper - http://www.runkeeper.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
  xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1">
<trk>
  <name><![CDATA[Running 7/9/13 5:12 pm]]></name>
  <time>2013-07-09T22:12:45Z</time>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="46.414311000" lon="-94.356703000"><ele>386.7</ele><time>2013-07-09T22:12:45Z</time></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="46.414328000" lon="-94.356708000"><ele>386.0</ele><time>2013-07-09T22:12:46Z</time></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="46.414404000" lon="-94.356637000"><ele>385.6</ele><time>2013-07-09T22:12:49Z</time></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="46.414486000" lon="-94.356562000"><ele>385.4</ele><time>2013-07-09T22:12:52Z</time></trkpt>
...
```

I'd like my script to process the first point, wait 1 second, then process the second, wait 3 seconds before processing the third, and then another 3 seconds before processing the last one...and so on. It might not matter at all, but I'm taking this data and updating a firebase database, so there's other "async" stuff I need to do with each data point.

I can get the data into an array no problem, so I tried to use a simple foreach loop with some setTimeout calls, but I was firing off a bunch of updates at the same time, where each was delayed a bit. Then I tried using observables like so:

```
    // waypoints is an array of the ... waypoints
    //
    Observable.from(waypoints)
        .zip(Observable.timer(0, 1000), x => x)
        .subscribe(async waypoint => {
            // await'ing firebase stuff
        });
```

This let's me delay each data point with little code, but only by a fixed amount, and not using the intervals between each waypoint. I was trying to replace that `1000` with a variable I could udpate while processing the data points, but couldn't get it working yet.

Is there another way to use observables (or something else) to get this behavior?

*I am seeing that js is really not meant to work synchronously, but I spend a lot of time in C# so I'm not opposed to just using that, but am hoping to learn something new :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the  [`startWith`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) and [`pairwise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pairwise) operators emit the previous and current waypoints and can then use the [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) operator with an observable that is delayed by the appropriate amount:

```js
const waypoints = Rx.Observable.from([{
  lat: 46.414311000,
  lon: -94.356703000,
  time: Date.parse("2013-07-09T22:12:45Z")
}, {
  lat: 46.414328000,
  lon: -94.356708000,
  time: Date.parse("2013-07-09T22:12:46Z")
}, {
  lat: 46.414404000,
  lon: -94.356637000,
  time: Date.parse("2013-07-09T22:12:49Z")
}, {
  lat: 46.414486000,
  lon: -94.356562000,
  time: Date.parse("2013-07-09T22:12:52Z")
}]);

const replay = waypoints
  .startWith(null)
  .pairwise()
  .concatMap(([previous, current]) => previous ?
    Rx.Observable.of(current).delay(current.time - previous.time) :
    Rx.Observable.of(current)
  )
  .subscribe(waypoint => console.log(waypoint));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I knew there'd be some combo of rxjs operators that could do this. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to quite do what I was hoping. It works for the first few waypoints, but then it just emits the last point over and over. You can see it in the snippet where the third waypoint it never emitted, but the last one is emitted twice. In my larger file the last waypoint is emitted many, many times.

Comment: Updated the snippet to not mutate the state - which seems to have been the problem.

Comment: I've updated it again. It's simpler if you use [`startWith`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) and [`pairwise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pairwise).